# How best to run a raspberry Pi 4 from a 12V DC supply

Tags: pi-4, power-supply, usb-power

The Raspberry Pi 4B uses the USB-C input as its power supply. To the best of my knowledge a full power USB-C supply is 20V or is it any voltage up to 20V?

If it's variable, is there a good way of going from a 12V 2.1-5.5mm DC jack to USB-C to power the Pi 4B. Thanks

Comment: Not easily, since part of the USB-C protocol is that the connected device *negotiates an appropriate voltage* from the supply.  The Pi 4 probably does the properly, since we haven't seen reports of them getting fried here.  But the supply must also do this properly, or at least, it must only put out 5V if you are trying to create a "dumb" supply.  Technically, it looks like USB-C "without PD" (= this "power delivery" feature) should only supply 5V: https://www.digikey.ca/en/articles/designing-in-usb-type-c-and-using-power-delivery-for-rapid-charging

Comment: See https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?p=2023781

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Pi's USB-C port is 5V only.

I suggest you use a UBEC (or similar) to convert the 12V DC to 5V.

Feed the 5V into the USB-C socket or (as I would do) into pins 4 (5V) and 6 (ground) of the expansion header.

Comment: Ah ok, got the wrong end of the stick somewhere then. So from the sounds of it, this is the sort of thing I am after? https://thepihut.com/products/ubec-dc-dc-step-down-buck-converter-5v-3a-output

Comment: Yes (I am thrifty so get mine from ebay).